# What's the Right Way to access static properties of subclasses in static methods of superclasses in PHP?

Tags: php, class, inheritance

Say I've got the following:

```
<?php
abstract class MyParent
{
    public static $table_name;

    public static get_all(){
        return query("SELECT * FROM {$this->table_name}");
    }

    public static get_all2(){
        return query("SELECT * FROM ".self::table_name);
    }
}

class Child extends MyParent
{   public static $table_name = 'child'; }
?>
```

Assuming that `query` is correctly defined, neither of these methods does what I want: get_all() throws `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /path/to/foo.php on line xx` because `$this` is an instance variable.

and get_all2() throws `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'table_name' in /path/to/foo.php on line xx` because `self` is statically determined.

It seems like this kind of thing is the whole point of inheritance, so it should be possible at least easily, if not elegantly. (This is PHP after all.)

What *should* I be doing?

Comment: Why do both answers start by saying `self::$table_name` when that doesn't work? Bizarre! At least they eventually say to use late static binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change `self::table_name` to `self::$table_name` - note the dollar sign. But the best way is to use PHP 5.3's static keyword:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

The `self` keyword references only the class that static proparty was defined, so it is wrong in this case, as you need to get static property 'inherited' from parent class. The keyword 'static' in this case will resolve correct caller class and work correctly.

Comment: Dammit that's not what *static* means! That's dynamic class-level binding. The fact that PHP followed Java's example and used a stupid keyword to denote class-level variables shouldn't affect every other part of their language.

Comment: This is what statis does _also_ mean in PHP. That's why I've put a link to the PHP manual - just to be sure that one won't take it as usual static.

Comment: It is a misnomer in that it has nothing to do with `static` functions or properties. i.e., `static::foo()` can be a call to either a static function or a non-static function. The manual says it was so named with an "internal perspective," but that's really just a poor excuse.

Comment: Sorry Tomasz, I wasn't criticizing you, and I should have started that comment with "thanks" instead of "dammit".

Comment: This really does not matter, as long as we are discussing technical details, and not calling names on everyone else. :) If you are satisfied with my answer, acceptance will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: So: Thanks!

"Static", though, is a *Terrible* way to say "Class-level", which is what it means in PHP and Java. It sort of makes sense in Java but it *really* doesn't make sense in PHP--based on my limited understanding of the language/interpreter, of course. It's just inherited cruft and the leakage to the corruption of the discipline-wide term "late binding" or "dynamic binding" is just dumb.

Comment: Also: I would appreciate it if you would point out in your answer that `self::$table_name` actually does the wrong thing, and `static::$table_name` does the right thing. I'll accept it then.

Comment: Static is the thing I tend not to use in general, without going down to every single case. I've realized that Dependency Injection idea is much better. ;']

Answer (score 4):

`self::$table_name`, although you probably want `static::$table_name`.

Comment: static::$table_name is exactly what I want, self::$table_name does the wrong thing.